# How to upload an image using redux toolkit query?

Tags: reactjs, http, redux, jsx, redux-toolkit

I have the following code:

```html
<input type="file" onchange={fileChange} accept="image/*" />
```

```js
function fileChange({target: { files }}){
const file = files[0]
uploadFile(file)
});
```

```js
const imgBB = createApi({
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({ baseUrl: 'https://api.imgbb.com/1/' }),
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    upload: builder.mutation({
      query: (file) => ({
        url: '/upload?key=MY_API_KEY',
        method: 'POST',
        body: file,
      }),
    }),
  }),
})

export default imgBB
export const { useUploadMutation } = imgBB
```

I am getting the following response from the server:

[image]

(https://imgbb.com/)

Answer (score 1):

In order to send a file, u need to send it using form data. I suggest you change your code like this:

```
const imgBB = createApi({
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({ baseUrl: 'https://api.imgbb.com/1/' }),
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    upload: builder.mutation({
      query: (file) => ({
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("file", file); // your frontend and backend file name "file" might have to be the same
        url: '/upload?key=MY_API_KEY',
        method: 'POST',
        body: formData,
      }),
    }),
  }),
})

export default imgBB
export const { useUploadMutation } = imgBB
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are looping the images if you have multiple images and if you're using typescript that the images and files are typed properly, the most most important part for multiple images is the for loop in conjunction (when using typescript) that the interface in my case picture: FileList and image: File are exported to the Mutation.

This worked for me, Im using useForm, SumbmitHandler and FormProvider from 'react-hook-form'

```
export interface FormValues {
  picture: FileList;
  image: File;
}

const Pictures = () => {
const [createProduct, { isError, error, data }] = useCreateProductMutation();

const { register, handleSubmit,} = useForm<FormValues>();
const methods = useForm<FormValues>();
   const onSubmit: SubmitHandler<FormValues> = async (data) => {
  const formData = new FormData();
   for (let i = 0; i < data.picture.length; i++) {
     formData.append("image", data.picture[i]);
     }
   //If you only need to sumbit one image you can set one image instead of the loop.
   // formData.set('image', images[0])

       createProduct(formData);
     };

  return (
    <>
        <FormProvider {...methods} >
          <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
           <input
            type="file"
            name="file"
            multiple
            accept="image/*"
            {...register("picture")}
             />
              <button type="submit">
              Submit
              </button>
           </form>
         </FormProvider>
     </>
    );
   };
  export default Pictures;
```

Comment: But it worked, and they said that it's not a RTKQ after all

Answer (score 0):

I think the people expected something like that.

```js
export const AwsS3ListingFilesApi = createApi({
  endpoints: builder => ({
    uploadFile: builder.mutation({
      query: ({ listingId, file }) => {
        const body = new FormData();
        body.append('Content-Type', file.type);
        body.append('file', file);

        return {
          url: `${listingId}/upload`,
          method: 'POST',
          body,
        }
      },
    }),
  }),
});
```